# How to use AutoFocus and Flash for camera in Blackberry Jde 5.0.0

Tags: blackberry-jde

In my application i need to Enable Flash and Enable AutoFocus for camera in blackberry jde 5.0.0

Help me, please.

Regards,
Sampath

Answer (score 1):

```
player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
player.realize();
player.start();
VideoControl vc = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
focusControl = (FocusControl) player.getControl("javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.FocusControl");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Enable Flash](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/amms/control/camera/FlashControl.html) `setFlash()`

[Enable AutoFocus](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/amms/control/camera/FocusControl.html) `setFocus()`